# Android 11 emulator gives PCI bus not available for hda

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to build android 11 and run an emulator. So far I've followed the instructions in https://source.android.com/setup/build/building. When I run emulator I get this:

```
emulator: Android emulator version 30.9. 0.0 (build_id 7651928) (CL:N/A)
emulator: INFO: ignore sdcard for arm at api level >= 30
cannot add library /home/ivan/Android/prebuilds/android_emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
added library /home/ivan/Android/prebuilds/android_emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.so
configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
emulator: INFO: ignore sdcard for arm at api level >= 30
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:288: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
qemu-system-aarch64: PCI bus not available for hda
```

Any ideas what that is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 12):

Adding "-qemu -machine virt" after emulator seems to fix that issue. However I think in some cases that might not work and you will be stuck on a black screen emulator.

Comment: Did you solved black screen?

Comment: `-gpu swiftshader_indirect` solves this. Though it renders painfully slow.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator#support_for_arm_binaries_on_android_9_and_11_system_images

You need either Android API level 28 (x86) or level 30 (any system image), my setup is making build-tools, platforms, and system images (google_apis;x86) on the same API level (28) from android-commandlinetools and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this error when I used the `arm64-v8a` system image for my virtual device. This was fixed when I switched to the recommended `x86` image. This should work with API level 30.

Back in February, [someone suggested that the arm64 package could be broken](https://groups.google.com/g/android-platform/c/YofAOCEtlFk) but I don't think this is the case as I was able to use it earlier this year on a different machine. This could be something specific to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that problem too, I think from android 11, the official virtual machine targets didn't support arm/arm64 anymore, or only supported on arm64 host machine line apple M1, that's sad.